# How to prevent app crashing when uploading image when there is no internet connection

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the objective C code:

```
NSString * url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tragicclothing.co.uk/Retort/imageupload.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSMutableData *body = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: audio/basic\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:_imageDataToSend];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    //Send the Request
    NSData* returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request
                                               returningResponse: nil error: nil];
    //serialize to JSON
    NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    //parsing JSON
    bool success = [result[@"success"] boolValue];
    if(success){ 
        NSLog(@"Success=%@",result[@"msg"]); 
    }else{ 
        NSLog(@"Fail=%@",result[@"msg"]);
    }
```

And it works fine when connected to the internet but when it is not I get the error:

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'*

Comment: Generally, you should check return values and error codes. You also shall check the HTTP status code from the response and also the MIME type. You didn't, thus you have no idea what went wrong ;)

Comment: Don't use synchronous request, unless the whole code runs in a separate thread. Use asynchronous instead to not block the ui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check for connectivity before performing network request.

Once you have [downloaded](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) and imported `Reachbility.m` and `Reachbility.h`  files

create a helper function:

```
-(BOOL)IsConnected{
  Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
  NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

  return !(networkStatus == NotReachable);    
}
```

Then use it

```
if([self IsConnected]){
 //connected!
 //upload your image
}
else{
  //not connected to internet!
}
```

---

**Very important**

If your project is not using arc

- go to target >
- Build Phase >
- double click the Reachability file
- add `-fno-objc-arc`

Comment: It's preferred to just try a network request, and only IFF the connection couldn't be established, test for reachability.

Comment: Thats another way to do it, I have also seen people pinging google.

Comment: how do you import the two .h and .m files?
I have done: #import "Reachability.h" 
#import "Reachability.m"

Comment: I am getting an error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: yes, download the files , add them to your project, and import only the `.h file`  `#import Reachability.h`

Comment: it is still not working... weird obviously thinks it is still connected in flight mode

Comment: Be careful with just doing this, you still need to check if returnData is nil before using it with NSJSONSerialization, returnData can be nil for multiple reasons not just there not being an internet connection.

Comment: @Maximilian Keep in mind that you still need to add the code suggested by the other answers. Just because you add a reachability check doesn't mean that you will always successfully get back your data.

Comment: Yes the guys are right, my answer addresses the connectivity issue.. See the other answers for more checks

Comment: @meda I removed the exclamation mark and it is working? Should it not be? is Guilherme Torres Castro answer better would you say?

Comment: @meda may you look at our discussion

Comment: @Maximilian I am at the chat

Comment: @meda sorry I am there now!

Comment: hello @meda sorry to keep bothering you but can you have a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329975/getting-zero-data-from-video-url

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!returnData){
    return; // or handle no connection error here
}else{
   NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    //parsing JSON
    bool success = [result[@"success"] boolValue];
   if(success){ 
        NSLog(@"Success=%@",result[@"msg"]); 
   }else{ 
       NSLog(@"Fail=%@",result[@"msg"]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The app is crashing on this line

```
NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

because the value of returnData is nil. All you need to do is test if this object is nil before passing into NSJSONSerialization like so

```
NSData* returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request
                                           returningResponse: nil error: nil];

if (returnData == nil)
{
    // Handle No Data returned from server
    // This can happen from no internet connection, from a server error or many other things
}
else 
{
    // Parse the Data
    NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    //parsing JSON
    bool success = [result[@"success"] boolValue];
    if(success){ 
        NSLog(@"Success=%@",result[@"msg"]); 
    }else{ 
        NSLog(@"Fail=%@",result[@"msg"]);
    }
}
```