# data from camera video returning zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, nsdata

this is my code for getting a video from `UIImagePickerController` :

```
- (IBAction)takeVideo:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    self.movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
    self.movieController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [self.movieController setContentURL:self.movieURL];
    [self.movieController.view setFrame:CGRectMake (15, 125, 292, 390)];
    self.movieController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.movieController.view];
    [self.movieController play];

    NSString *myString = [self.movieURL absoluteString];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myString];
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:videoData.length countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile]);
    [self setImageDataToSend:videoData];

}
```

where:

```
NSString *myString = [self.movieURL absoluteString];
        NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myString];
        NSLog(@"%@",[NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:videoData.length countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile]);
        [self setImageDataToSend:videoData];
```

Is returning zero? How come when it obviously is showing data?

Comment: what Xcode shows when you log --> NSLog(@"%@",self.movieURL);

Comment: @AnandK `file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/F8D3F96F-E837-4F2A-9064-AB0DA1E092BD/tmp/capture-T0x17806a140.tmp.KkRRxZ/capturedvideo.MOV`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the size like this

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                            attributesOfItemAtPath:[self.movieURL path] error:&error];

if (!error) {
    NSLog(@" size= %@",[attributes objectForKey:NSFileSize]);
}else{
    NSLog(@"err= %@",error);
}
```

if you want KB

```
NSString *myString = [self.movieURL path];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myString];
NSLog(@"%@",[NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:videoData.length countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile]);
```